# Github private repository and releases visibility

Tags: git, github, repository, release, publish

I have a simple question about Github. If I make a new "Release" (with a tag) with some binaries and source code in a "private" repository, will this Release stay private too (hidden from the public)? or once published, anyone can see the Release/tag regardless of whether the repository is marked as public or private? I couldn't find information about this in the documentation.

Comment: if the repo is private, the releases are private too, and anyone who isn't authorized to access the repo won't be able to see them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your repo is private, only people who have read access to it will be able to see the releases. The public won't.

From [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/releasing-projects-on-github/about-releases):

> Anyone with read access to a repository can view and compare releases, but only people with write permissions to a repository can manage releases.